# replacement for sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory newConstructorForSerialization

Tags: java, reflection

there is a project that uses `newConstructorForSerialization(Class<?> incomingArgument, Object.class.getDeclaredConstructor())` to get a constructor that is later used to create objects before they are actually initialized with `foreach field  field.set(instance, fieldObj);`.

This api is deprecated in the new java releases and compiler produces many warnings during build so I would like to replace it with something up-to-date. If I understand this code correctly it returns a public available constructor for `incomingArgument` that only initializes `Object` superclass fields, am I right?

So it solves three tasks:

1. get the right amount of memory from `mConstructor.newInstance()`;
2. avoids unnecessary field initialization (they will be set later);
3. makes the constructor publicly available (it could be private or not be presented).

Is there a way to achieve the same without using deprecated api-s?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance` via google protobuf proxy (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/520c601c99012101c816b6ccc89e8d6fc28fdbb8/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/UnsafeUtil.java#L98), so now this dependency is compiled separately so I don't see the warnings and I could expect that google fixes it if `sun.misc.Unsafe` stops working due to java updates.

Comment: `Unsafe.allocateInstance` is different - as it does not invoke a constructor - while the constructor for serialization invokes the constructor with no arguments of the first superclass that does not implement `Serializable`. This has some effects - for example, finalizers are only run after the constructor from `java,lang.Object` has been successfully run.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn, it is useful to know. I think in my scenario I don't need a finalizer but I will write some tests to show the difference between the versions.